# Bookshelf.js groupBy on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm building a program that uses Bookshelf to access a MySQL database. One of the things I'm trying to make is grouping data by two columns. But I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried using knex groupByRaw and lodash _.groupBy, but I don't think I'm using them in the right place.

Here's the situation:

**Table**

I'm storing timers in a table with the following columns: id, userID, projectID, startTime, stopTime.

I want to select the acumulative times for each user in a given calendar week.

My guess is the resulting query would be something like this:

`SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startTime, endTime)), userID, YEARWEEK(startTime, 1), projectID
FROM time
GROUP BY userID, YEARWEEK(startTime, 1)
HAVING projectID = 1`

Comment: did you got a solution for that?

Comment: @TzookBarNoy I'm afraid I never did :(

Answer (score 3):

Bit late, but for the record: you can call Knex's `groupBy` multiple times in succession. So:

```
  .groupBy("userID")
  .groupByRaw("YEARWEEK(startTime, 1)")
```

Comment: You answer is a little old by now, but it just saved my day. Chaining groupBy actually works, while comma separated column names didn't. I'am using knex with mysql, but it propably applies to bookshelf.js too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of repeating groupby word many times, use this syntax.

```
.groupBy(['userID','YEARWEEK(startTime, 1)'])
```